# Changing the position or hide a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this positioned over an image as default.

```
<div class="um">

            <div class="grum">
                <img src="" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="fixoum">
                <img src="" alt="">
            </div>
      </div>
```

CSS:
the image is positioned as absolute.

```
 .um{
        position: relative;
        top:0px;
        height: 325px;
        width: 650px;
    }
    
    .grum, .fixoum{
        position: relative;
        display: inline-flex;
        flex-direction:column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 70px;
        margin:0px;
    }
```

I've created a button so i can change the position of .grum and .fixoum.
My question is if i need to create another div and position that where i want or can i make it change with js?
If i need to create another div how can i hide the other after the button is selected?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your goal exactly? What happens when you click on a button, you just hide an image?

Comment: No. Its for a sports project. All the players have classes. For example, i have a formation of 4-4-2 over the tatical board (image) as default. I have a button which will change to a 4-3-3 formation. My doubt is how can i click the button and hide the 4-4-2 and change to the 4-3-3? Or can i change the players positioned to a new one?

Comment: While you will have to figure it out for your specific needs, you can indeed hide or display items on the page. I would go with a table of 4 by 4. You can then only hide the images you want depending on the formation you want. I can provide you with a little snippet showing you the basics if you'd like.